# Virtual host in Apache both with WWW and without

Tags: apache-http-server

How to setup local Apache to be both reachable with www(www.site.com) and without (site.com) in Windows 10?

Apache such: httpd-2.4.39-win64-VC15

Comment: Windows is totally unrelated. You may be looking for the `ServerAlias` directive...?

Comment: may you add example?

Comment: As @DanielB said, check the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directives.

Answer (score 1):

In **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       site.com
127.0.0.1   www.site.com
```

in **C:\Apache24\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/Apache24/htdocs/site.com
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com 
</VirtualHost>
```

It works!